# Mongodb: No *.system.namespaces

Tags: mongodb, console

I'm trying to repair a database through the console.

It's a replicaset with 3 members, I'm trying in a secondary and I always get the same error. When I list the available collections inside the db it doesn't show any *.namespace collection:

```
root@web:~#  mongo xxx.210.xxx.12:27017/admin -uXXXX -pXXXXXXX
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5
connecting to: xxx.210.xxx.12:27017/admin
xxxxxSet:SECONDARY> use facebook
switched to db facebook
xxxxxSet:SECONDARY> db.repairDatabase();
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "clone failed for facebook with error: namespace query failed     facebook.system.namespaces"
}
xxxxxSet:SECONDARY> show collections
xxxnts
xxes
xxxes_beta
system.indexes
system.users
told
```

Answer (score 1):

`show collections` hides some collections from view. You can run a direct find on the collection though:

```
> db.system.namespaces.find();
```

Which shows:

```
{ "name" : "test.fs.files" }
{ "name" : "test.system.indexes" }
{ "name" : "test.fs.files.$_id_" }
…
```

However, if yours is gone then try creating it:

```
db.createCollection( "facebook.system.namespaces" );
```